How can I pass JVM parameters to `allure` in my pipeline?
My pipeline has many stages that produce allure results. I aggregate them in the end.

allure([
        includeProperties: false,
        jdk: '',
        properties: [],
        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
        results: allure_results,
        report: "${env.WORKSPACE}/allure-report.zip"
])


Recently, the number of stages grew, so the pipeline runs in an out-of-heap-space issue.
[Pipeline] allure
[2024-04-15T03:30:05.458Z] [myjob] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/ru.ya...llation/allure/bin/allure generate 
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/myjob/aaa_1_2__allure_results

  [300 lines omitted]

  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/myjob/zzz_8_8__allure_results
  -c -o /var/jenkins_home/workspace/myjob/allure-report.zip
[2024-04-15T03:31:59.167Z] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2024-04-15T03:31:59.168Z]      at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1180)

I want to pass the -Xmx2G parameter to the allure but can't find a way to do so.
What I tried:

Using properties block with JAVA_OPTS:


allure([
        includeProperties: false,
        jdk: '',
        properties: [[key: 'JAVA_OPTS', value: '-Xmx2G']],
        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
        results: allure_results,
        report: "${env.WORKSPACE}/allure-report.zip"
])

This does not look like it's working (tested by providing invalid string).

Using environment variable:

withEnv(['JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2G']) {
    allure([
            includeProperties: true,
            jdk: '',
            properties: [],
            reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
            results: allure_results,
            report: "${env.WORKSPACE}/allure-report.zip"
    ])
}

This also does not look like it's working (tested by providing invalid string).
How can I pass a Java parameter to allure command line?
